# SDN Security - why not attack the controller itself?

Tags: network, routing, software

I have been looking into SDN (Software Defined Networking) and one advantage of using this is to be able to redirect traffic to stop DDoS attacks.  The traffic is ultimately thrown away.  My question is if a network is using SDN couldn't an attacker just as easily attack the controller itself?  Rather than flooding routers or attacking the hosts or applications, an attacker might craft traffic streams simply to increase the interactions between the switches and the controller.  Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Collin, welcome to security.SE. I had a go at making your title less vague, which should get you more views. Feel free to edit it further by clicking the 'edit' link below the question text.

Comment: There was a recent [risky.biz](http://risky.biz/RB366) podcast about SDN. Here is a link to a [blog post](http://onosproject.org/2015/04/03/sdn-and-security-david-jorm/) as well.